# Why 早 in "good morning" is read as HA-YO but no such reading of that kanji is in a dictionary?

Tags: kanji, readings, phrases

I see お**早**うございます in a dictionary also being written as お**はよ**うございます but why is **早** even there if it's read as HA-YA, not HA-YO? How do they know how to morph readings of kanji in a phrase into something else if it's not in the dictionary?

Comment: Comment below if the link above doesn't answer your question.